# Add a newline into a filename with `mv`

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting, newlines

*It's a serious question. I test some `awk` scripts and I need files with a newline in their names.*

---

Is it possible to add a newline into a filename with `mv`?

I now, I can do this with `touch`:

```
touch "foo
bar"
```

With touch I added the newline character per copy and paste. But I can't write `foo`<kbd>Return</kbd>`bar` in my shell.

How can I rename a file, to have a newline in the filename?

---

*Edit 2015/06/28;  07:08 pm*

To add a newline in `zsh` I can use, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you making some joke or trick to a friend?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, it's a serious question. I test some awk scripts. But I can remove the question even if it displeases you so much.

Comment: Don't remove the question, it is useful. But really avoid new lines in filenames as much as possible.

Comment: What makes you think doing it with `mv` would be any different from doing it with `touch`? Did you try the same thing?

Comment: @Kevin With `touch` I added the newline character per copy and paste. But I can't write "foo<return>bar" in my shell.

Comment: Well, you can copy and paste into the `mv` command just as easily as `touch`.

Comment: BTW, in zsh you can also enter a newline with `esc` `return` (not together, release the `esc` before hitting `return`)

Comment: Why are you using copy and paste to type a newline?

Comment: I am using `zsh`. I can type `"foo [return] bar"` without problem. Please describe what is the problem with the standard [return].

Comment: @danielAzuelos Thanks, that works for me. No idea what I did wrong.

Comment: One possibility might be that you changed IFS within one of your shell contexts. To check it, type `echo "$IFS" | od -cx` within the shell context where you have trouble with the normal [return].

Comment: @danielAzuelos That may be, I have used IFS to this day. Thx =)

Comment: So let me suggest you to formulate more clearly your OP: Within a given shell environment I can't type a newline within a quoted string as in echo "a[return]b".

Comment: IFS shouldn't have any effect on quoted strings. And parsing of quoted strings should be independent of the command: it should works the same with `mv` as it does with `touch`.

Comment: This question is indeed very useful. Consider this situation. I have a Python script, and I use it both in Windows and Linux. The script has Windows-ending lines. It begins with "#/usr/bin/env python3\r" and Linux cannot handle that character "\r". So I created a symlink "python3\r" using these suggestions, and now the script is executable under Linux.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a bad idea (to have strange characters in file names) but you could do

```
 mv somefile.txt "foo
 bar"
```

(you could also have done `mv somefile.txt "$(printf "foo\nbar")"` or `mv somefile.txt foo$'\n'bar`, etc... details are specific to your shell. I'm using `zsh`)

Read more about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), e.g. [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Details could be shell-specific. But understand that `/bin/mv`  is given (by your shell), via [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), an *expanded* array of arguments: argument expansion and globbing is the responsibility of the invoking shell.

And you could even code a tiny C program to do the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  if (rename ("somefile.txt", "foo\nbar")) {
     perror("rename somefile.txt");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Save above program in `foo.c` , compile it with `gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo`  then run `./foo`

Likewise, you could code a similar script in Perl, Ruby, Python, Ocaml, etc....

But that is a bad idea. **Avoid newlines in filenames** (it will confuse the user, and it could break many scripts).

Actually, I even recommend to use only non-accentuated letters, digits, and `+-/._%`  characters (with `/`  being the directory separator) in file paths. "Hidden" files (starting with `.`) should be used with caution and parcimony. I believe using any kind of space in a file name is a mistake. Use an underscore instead (e.g. `foo/bar_bee1.txt`) or a minus (e.g. `foo/bar-bee1.txt`)

Comment: Yes, I know, that I can copy and paste a newline character, but how could I do that without copy and paste?

Comment: There isn't any copy or paste here. There is a typed newline after `foo`.

Comment: However it works also copy-pasting it

Comment: It is a bad idea for usual files, but a good test case, as the OP mentioned.

Comment: You can't put a `/` character in a file name.  At least, you can't in any filesystem I've ever heard of.

Comment: Of course `/` is the directory separator

Comment: `@` and `,` would be more harmless than `-` (like in first position) or `%`. All those recomendations are mainly to work around bugs in some applications (that break on filenames that are otherwise valid from the OS point of view). It feels backward to ask people to not use those characters rather than fixing their bugs.

Comment: Why do you believe `%` is more harmful than `@` (which has special meaning, e.g. for `scp`)?

Comment: Why does `''$'\n''` show in ls?

Comment: ohh the $ denotes escaped characters

Answer (score 20):

If you use bash, this command should work.

```
mv a $'b\nc'
```

Comment: Works with `zsh` also =)

Comment: bash, like zsh and FreeBSD sh copied that from ksh93.

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally forgot about $ in bash, while it was my own answer on SO advising using it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix/5694596#5694596

Comment: also : `a$'\n'c` should work in bash

Answer (score 6):

I know you asked for a `mv` solution, however, despite the warning, this can be easily done with `rename` (in the Perl package):

```
~/tmp$ touch foo
~/tmp$ rename 's/$/\nbar/' foo
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/share/perl5/File/Rename.pm line 69.
~/tmp$ ls
foo?bar
```

Comment: Thank you for the `rename`, a very good idea. +1

Answer (score 6):

One aspect of this problem isn't really about `awk` - and only a little bit about the shell.  The problem is that on a standard, canonical tty most of the time the kernel's tty discipline is buffering your input - just echoing it to your screen and nowhere else - so that it can efficiently handle backspacing and such-like.

However, when you press return or otherwise enter a newline, all of that buffered data is pushed at once to the reading application - usually your shell. You can observe this by watching for `$PS2` after entering a dangling quote. When the shell prints `$PS2` it's because its just read some block of your input and is not yet convinced you're through.

So, for convenience, what you need is some way of sending a `\n`ewline into the terminal buffer without having to push all of that other input immediately. The standard way to do so is w/ the key-sequence *`CTRL+V`* - which *quotes* for the terminal your next input character. Do *`CTRL+V`* then *`CTRL+J`* - because the latter is usually how to type a literal `\n`ewline. You'll know it's worked when you don't see `$PS2` because the shell still hasn't read your input.

Note though that when it *does* read that input your earlier *`CTRL+V`* will have made no difference for the shell at all - that only quotes it for the line-discipline. You'll definitely want to shell-quote the newline as well to do anything meaningful with it.

By the way, *`CTRL+V`* can be usefully applied in other ways - for example `"$(printf \\33)"` is not the only way to write an *`ESC`* character into a shell script - and it isn't even the most simple. You can literally enter any character your keyboard will send without the input driver attempting to interpret it if you just first escape it in this way.

I often like to use <tab>s on the command-line without the shell attempting to complete anything. Because shells which do completion will typically configure <tab> in a way synonymous to `stty eol \t`, to make their completion systems work, *`CTRL+V`* works for me even in unfamiliar environments.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning 'Ctrl+V'. I was about to post answer about it and then saw your explanation.